# In google sheets extracting words from column based on reference column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In this scenario, I have a reference column (A) of 6 types of devices, and a second column (B) of several thousand specific device names including the word from the reference column in the string.

I am trying to extract into a new column (C), from the column B just the relevant word from the string that corresponds to the reference column.

So far have been unsuccessful in finding the right working formula.

Comment: Please, edit your question to provide what you have tried so far and what were the errors, or the actual output versus the desired one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP function to search particular data and get desired result.